# button not pulling to left while using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have two buttons on my web page.  One is supposed to pull all the way to the left and the other to the right.  The right button gets pulled all the way to the right but the left stays in the center. Any ideas on what might be causing this?  I am using bootstrap v3.1.1.  I will paste a fiddle soon.

**HTML**

```
<button id="displayLeftMenu" class="pull-left">Left Menu</button>
<button id="displayRightMenu" class="pull-right">Right Menu</button>
```

I have also tried the following but the left button does not appear to pull all the way to the left (but the right one does).  :

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <button id="displayLeftMenu" class="pull-left">Left Menu</button>
    <button id="displayRightMenu" class="pull-right">Right Menu</button>    
</div>
```

There are no rules in CSS for displayLeftMenu or displayRightMenu.

Comment: Works fine here http://www.bootply.com/n4argo0K91. Do you have other code that could be causing a conflict?

Comment: It's work fine for me on JSfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/fVw8U/

Comment: probably there is a conflict on my end - pilot error.  I will check o my end and update the post.  Thanks to everyone who commented.  I noticed the same on jsfiddle as well.